# How to run a .bin file without using terminal

Tags: files, executable

How to run an executable .bin file without using terminal
Eg :qtcreator.bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step1: copy the file to the Desktop or home folder(for convenience )

step2: right click on the file and chose properties ,and check the allow the file to execute button

step3:rename the file to filename.bin to filename

step4:Double click on the program

## The above method wont work if the program needs root permission

Comment: it is not necessary to copy it to your home desktop. if it is on an external drive just mount the drive with executable permissions and follow the normal procedure.

Comment: By default ,file on the FAT and ntfs partition wont support exutable privilege

Answer (score 1):

open its properies and in one of the tabs(i cant recall which one) there is an option to make it executable.check it.
 thats it. just save the properties and then run the file.

Comment: Sorry it gaves excutale previlage to the file ,still it cant execute by double clicking ,it just opens open with dialog